# Tiling regularly breaks: window does not render in the same place where it registers clicks

Tags: pantheon, window-management

It's about a 50/50 chance when I try to tile Chrome windows to the left and right half of the screen whether or not it works. I haven't been able to reliably determine how to reproduce it.

What happens is I will open a new second window, and drag it to the side of the screen to snap it to that half. This will seem to succeed other than that the window stays visible in the place where I held it against the side, and doesn't move/resize to the indicated half. However, at this point, click events and such register on the place where the window *should* be rather than where it is, so it becomes nearly impossible to fix this without closing the window using Ctrl-W.

Any help trying to troubleshoot this? Has anyone noticed anything similar?

Comment: Can you try doing a video recording of what's happening? It's hard to really picture it.